# javascript: what's a good way to do an http post and see its response on another page/tab?

Tags: javascript, html, http

On my web page there are a couple of buttons like 'export as pdf' or 'export as xml'
This is very similar to google analytics web page.

when the user clicks on one of them (e.g. export as pdf) I need to post some data to the server and I want to get as a response the pdf file (different content type)

In javascript what's a good way to do this ? 
I mean, how do I post something and get the response on another window/tab (exactly like google analytics)

I need to post something because I need to pass information about the view that the user has created and that could be quite a lot of information.

The serverside is done I just don't know how to implement it in javascript.

Thanks

p.s.
I don't think I need ajax or any library to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the form `target` attribute to `_blank` to have the browser open up a new window/tab.

As in:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a form and submit it to a new page.

```
var newForm = document.createElement("form");
newForm.target = "formSub";
newForm.action = "postForm.php";
newForm.method= "post";
newForm.style.display = "none";

var newHidden = document.createElement("input");
newHidden.type="hidden";
newHidden.name="foo";
newHidden.value="bar";

newForm.appendChild(newHidden);
document.body.append(newForm);
newForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, one way to do this could be using indeed some AJAX function. You submit the user's choice using an `XMLHttpRequest` from JavaScript. Then instruct the server on how should it behave and get a response. Once you have this response just use JavaScript again to open a new tab with the content received. To make things simpler you can use jQuery which provides a nice API for AJAX calls.

If your web service is RESTful then you can simply open a new tab in JavaScript directly pointing to the resource (the pdf file) you need.